# What word means "the day after a specific day"?

Tags: single-word-requests

We have the word "eve" to mean the day before a specific day, like a holiday.  The day before Christmas is "Christmas Eve".

Is there a word that can be used to concisely say "the day after Christmas", such as "I disposed of my Christmas tree on Christmas *XXXX*"?

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm not concerned with Christmas *specifically*, but with a way to say "the day after a specific, named day".  Therefore, "the second day of Christmas", while interesting, is not a valid answer to this question, unless you can also say "the second day of Presidents' Day", which -- although "Presidents' Day Eve" doesn't sound a lot better, either -- does not seem correct.

Comment: The day after Christmas is Boxing Day in the UK. I don't think there's a general word for the day after holidays in general.

Comment: There's a special word for the night before holidays because we often have parties then (since we don't have to go to bed early), and sometimes take off early from work. There's not as much special about the day after, so we don't need a word for it.

Comment: There is _morrow_ but it is literary or archaic.

Comment: In Britain, Australia, New Zealand, South Africa etc it is popularly Boxing Day. But in the Anglican ecclesiastical calendar it is *St Stephen's Day*, as it is across Catholic Europe, such as in France.

Comment: There are, of course, twelve days of Christmas, the last one (Twelfth Night) being 5th January when the decorations come down. In Britain many people take the whole fortnight off work as an important mid-winter break.

Comment: @WS2: Decorations? Oh, you mean the ones that are put up on the morrow of Thanksgiving? ;-)

Comment: @Drew Don't know anything about Thanksgiving. There is no particular rule about how soon you put up your Christmas decorations, but anyone with them still up after Twelfth Night (Feast of the Epiphany) is inviting bad luck all year.

Comment: @WS2: In CommerceLand, decorations for the next holiday are put up as those for the last one are being taken down, which is the very next day (stroke of midnight, if possible). For example, decorations for St. Patrick's Day (green; March 17) are put up as those for President's Day (red, white, & blue; 3rd Monday of Feb) are taken down.

Comment: @Drew The difference in Britain, as an American colleague of mine living in Britain once expressed it is that 'In Britain Christmas is like American Christmas, Thanksgiving, St Patrick's Day, George Washington's Birthday, and the Fourth of July, all rolled into a fortnight'.

Comment: @WS2: We don't have Washington's Birthday as a holiday anymore. During Nixon's reign, Washington's and Lincoln's birthdays were replaced as holidays with the single "Presidents Day". That pretty much puts all of our presidents on the same footing (including Mr Nixon, of course).

Comment: @Drew No, that was a Reagan-era move to allow the creation of Martin Luther King, Jr. Day in January without increasing the number of federal holidays. And on the federal calendar, the Feb. holiday is still listed as Washington's Birthday.

Comment: @choster: Actually, it was apparently [1968](http://www.archives.gov/publications/prologue/2004/winter/images/uniform-monday-holiday-law.jpg), so LBJ - not Nixon or Ray-Gun. Various reasons were given for it. The name *Presidents Day* is still not the official name, as you point out. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington%27s_Birthday).

Comment: I just started saying Aft as in Christmas Aft

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"The morrow of…"

Strictly this means "the morning of", but to talk of "the morrow" would be to talk of the *coming* morning, and so "the morrow" is the next day. Alas "on the morrow of Christmas" would be a tad ambiguous for this reason with it being more likely to mean Christmas morning, unless one was speaking during Christmas day.

Conversely, *eve* does not strictly mean "the day before" but the evening of. Since days were once reckoned from sundown to sundown, Christmas would start on what we would now consider the sundown of 24th December, and so the evening start of Christmas—Christmas Eve—happens on the day prior to the bulk of it, by the modern reckoning of dates moving upon the stroke of midnight. This goes some way to explain why some European countries have a bigger celebratory meal on the 24th than the 25, and why Hallowe'en is on the night before, rather than after All Hallows; by the old reckoning, the day had started at sundown.

"The morrow of…" is not in very common use any more. Nor for that matter is *eve* other than as preserved in "Christmas Eve" and the like and figurative uses like "eve of destruction".

Considering this, and the potential for considering it either as the morning during or the morning after, the simple phrase "the day after…" is much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *Twelve Days of Christmas*, the day after Christmas Day is the ***Second Day of Christmas*** for most churches.

> The Twelve Days of Christmas is a festive Christian season to celebrate the nativity of Jesus. In most Western Church traditions Christmas Day is the First Day of Christmas and the Twelfth Day falls on 5 January, but for others, the twelve days begin on 26 December and end on 6 January.
>   <sub>(Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Days_of_Christmas))</sub>

So, you would say:

> I disposed of my Christmas tree on the *Second Day of Christmas*.

It is also know as *Boxing Day* in Great Britain (and former colonies).

For a generic term, I don't think there is an improvement upon *morrow*, other than to stick with *the day after*. According to N-grams, [***day after*** is preferred over ***morrow of***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=day%20after%2Cmorrow%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cday%20after%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmorrow%20of%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Interestingly, [***day after Christmas*** is much preferred over ***day after Christmas Day***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=day%20after%20Christmas%20Day%2C%20day%20after%20Christmas&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cday%20after%20Christmas%20Day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cday%20after%20Christmas%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Comment: St. Stephen's Day is the Second Day of Christmas, because Christmas is a twelve-day feast, so that positions a day within a period of more than one day, rather than indicate a day after another.

Comment: @JonHanna: Thanks for the info. I hoped my answer was clear in that *Second Day or Christmas* was providing an identity for the day after Christmas to complete the sentence example specifically.

Answer (score -2):

There is no word like this in English. It's available in many other languages, but not English.

Comment: can you provide references or examples?